# Connect JSF to Hibernate and upload to OpenShift

Tags: hibernate, jpa, openshift

I want to create web application which use JSF and Hibernate. I've created it locally and now I want to upload it to OpenShift server. I'm new in JSF/Hibernate and I don't know how can I configure it. Can someone write some possibilities to connects JSF with Hibernate? It works locally and looks like this:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="StudioBMPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>entity.article.Article</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studiobm?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Code responsible to connect with mysql:
    package service;

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class DBManager {

    private static DBManager instance;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private DBManager() {}

    public synchronized static DBManager getManager() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DBManager();
    }

    return instance;
    }

    public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
    if (emf == null) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StudioBMPU");
    }

    return emf;
    }

    public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
    return this.createEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    public void closeEntityManagerFactory() {
    if (emf !=null) {
        emf.close();
    }
    }

}
```

Are there some other possibilities to connect with Hibernate? Maybe someone also knows where should I place persistence.xml file before openshift git commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that persistence.xml was configured in wrong way. I use EclipseLink to connect with database and the problem was that I used javax.persistence.jdbc.* as a namespace for configuration. When I changed this to eclipselink.jdbc.* app finally started to work.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the connection values directly in *persistence.xml* you should use filtering and use variables in the file. During a local build you filter in the development values. To deploy to OpenShift you create a *openshift* profile which defines the right values for OpenShift. When you push to OpenShift and the app gets build, the *openshift* profile gets activated by default.

Comment: Thanks, I understand you but I still don't know where I should place persistence.xml for OpenShift.

Comment: The location of persistence.xml does not change. It goes into META-INF.